# Creating a sub folder inside a root installation?

Tags: installation

Currently I have a root wordpress installation at www.mysite.com.

I've added a new folder /store in the root and added in a blank html. However, I can't seem to access the folder by going to www.mysite.com/store.

Any idea how I can do this?

****Update****

I realised when I'd encountered this issue there was no .htaccess file.

It seems like after I've added the .htaccess with a rewriterule to index.php, it all works.

How does wordpress exactly do it's rewrites without a .htaccess in the first place?

Comment: can you access the file by naming it? like `http://site.com/store/index.html` ?

Comment: @Sisir yes, after I added a .htaccess to rewrite all incoming uris to /index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you couldn't access the folder. Maybe you wanna check your `.htaccess` file first. The default rewrite conditions for apache created by WordPress should include the following two lines, which prevents the redirecting to `index.php` if a physical file or directory is found.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

You could force a redirect with another rewrite condition for your directory, but this should not be necessary.

E.g.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/store/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```